# Push existing element of std::deque to the front?

Tags: c++, stl, stack, queue, deque

I'm looking for a nice way to approach this problem. Not even sure if std::deque is what I want, but basically I need a container that I'll access front frequently and then move existing items to the front and add new ones to the front as well. Any way to do that with deque?

Comment: If you want to move items around, perhaps a better data structure would be a linked list (`std::list`)? `std::dequeue` does support random access, but it's likely not quite as fast for moving things around, depending on what you're doing with the elements...

Comment: I agree with @Cameron, you probably want a `list`. To move elements, `list::splice` them into a second list and then splice them back into the front of the original list.

Answer (score 2):

For `std::deque<T>` you can access elements efficiently everywhere and you can efficiently add/remove elements at the front and at the end. However, `std::deque<T>` doesn't quite like to move objects from the middle: it will need to fill the gap in some form. Basically, moving an element would amount to a combination of an insert and an erase.

Using `std::vector<T>` or `std::deque<T>` may still be the best option when moving objects assuming neither the objects themselves nor the container is huge. For example, using a `std::vector<T>` of 1000 pointers and moving objects within is probably still faster than playing with a node-based container. At which sizes exactly the choices of containers change depends on your typical access pattern, the size of the object, etc.

For large objects or large containers you might want to use `std::list<T>` together with the `splice()` operation. ... and if all of these are too slow you might want to explain in more details what you are actually trying to and possibly use a different strategy and/or a more specialized containers like, e.g., a priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method push_front :).

Comment: Oh really? What argument should I use? Existing element value?

Comment: @user: You can remove the element using `erase()`, then re-add it to the front using `push_front()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using `deque`. But can we do it using list as well ? (yes)

### Push to front

```
std::deque<int> contents;

contents.push_front(1);
contents.push_front(2);
contents.push_front(3);

// Now has 3,2,1
```

### lookup and move to front

```
// access 1 and move 1 to front
for(auto&& x:contents)
{
    if(1 == x)
    {
        contents.front.swap(x);
        break;
    }

}
```